# WooCommerce custom checkout page in theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to create custom checkout page in my theme? I mean to create custom checkout.php document I do not want to edit WooCommerce default theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is achieved by overriding the WooCommerce checkout.php file in the plugin itself by placing it in your theme's WooCommerce directory. You are right not to want to edit the plugin because any updates will render such changes obsolete. You can see the following files you would want to override here: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/master/templates/checkout

Your directory should look something as follows:

```
themeroot/
   single.php
   page.php
   etc..
   woocommerce/
       templates/
            checkout/
                form-checkout.php
                form-billing.php
                etc
```

You can learn more about creating Custom WordPress themes by [viewing the document](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/). You will want to duplicate and work of these files to create your custom checkout page.